# recurrence relation with non-constant coefficient from higher derivative

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Recently,I came across a question about higher derivative of a special class of rational function. I need help to solve a second order  recurrence relations:

$x_n+bnx_{n-1}+an(n-1)x_{n-2}=0$, where $b,a$ are some real numbers with $x_0=1,x_1=-b$.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y_n=\frac{x_n}{n!}$. Then the recurrence becomes
$$ y_n+by_{n-1}+ay_{n-2}=0.$$

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

so we get the answer $$x_n=\frac{2^{-n-1} \left((n+1) n! \left(\sqrt{b^2-4
   a}-b\right)^{n+1}-(n+1)! \left(-\sqrt{b^2-4
   a}-b\right)^{n+1}\right)}{(n+1) \sqrt{b^2-4 a}}$$

Comment: @Graubner Thanks for the details.

Comment: @Graubner.  It can be reduced to the following:$$x_n=\frac{n!}{2^{n+1}\sqrt{b^2-4a}}[(\sqrt{b^2-4a}-b)^{n+1}-(-b-\sqrt{b^2-4a})^{n+1}]$$

Comment: @Graubner. How can we get the solution  for the following nonhomogeneous Recurrence Relations: $$y_{n}+by_{n-1}+ay_{n-2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{b^2-4a}}[(\frac{\sqrt{b^2-4a}-b}{ 2 })^{n+1}-  (\frac{-\sqrt{b^2-4a}-b}{ 2 })^{n+1}  ]$$